# Index only cells in a column from another sheet if another cell in same row has a value greater than 0

Tags: excel, excel-formula

So I have an example below of what I'm wanting to do. 
Basically I need to `Index Column B` from `Sheet 1` into `Sheet 2` BUT ONLY if the values in `Column W` in `Sheet 1` are greater than 0. If it's not then I don't want it to be included in. The only column to Index is `B` starting from row 5 to say 100. Same for `Column W`.

I was trying to do it myself as I found [This](https://www.get-digital-help.com/2009/09/28/extract-all-rows-from-a-range-that-meet-criteria-in-one-column-in-excel/) which is very similar as what I'm wanting to do but I couldn't figure it out.

```
    Sheet 1

Row# Column B | Column(s)…  | Column W
     =================================
 5)  Thing 1  |             |    0
 6)  Thing 2  |             |    3
 7)  Thing 3  |             |    0
 8)  Thing 4  |             |    1 

    Sheet 2

Row# Column B |  Column C   | Column D
     =================================
 5)  Thing 2  |      3      |
 6)  Thing 4  |      1      |
 7)           |             |
 8)           |             |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT #3**

You can use either **SMALL**, **LARGE** function to return the values from `Column B` on your `Sheet1`.

Presume you have given the following **names**:

1. **Sheet1ColB**: `Sheet1!B5:B100`
2. **Sheet1ColW**: `Sheet1!W5:W100`

Here is the formula to be put in **Cell B5** on your `Sheet2`. Please note it is an array formula so you need to press **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** to confirm.

`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1ColB,SMALL(IF((Sheet1ColW>0)*(LEN(Sheet1ColW)>0),ROW(Sheet1ColW)),ROW()-4)-4),"")}`

or

`{=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1ColB,LARGE(IF((Sheet1ColW>0)*(LEN(Sheet1ColW)>0),ROW(Sheet1ColW)),ROW()-4)-4),"")}`

You can then use **INDEX+MATCH** to return the value from **Column W** on your `Sheet1` in **Column C** on your `Sheet2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1ColW,MATCH(B5,Sheet1ColB,0)),"")
```

[image]

In the above screen-shot Solution 2 is using **AGGREGATE** which follows the same logic as **SMALL/LARGE**.

As you can see the sample data has taken into account duplicated values in `Sheet 1 Col W`, blank cells in both **Column W** and **Column B** on `Sheet1`, and blank cells, negative value or `0` value in **Column B** only on `Sheet1`.

Cheers :)

Comment: That would work except for the values in "Column C" aren't necessarily going to be different. If I have a few that have value 1 then only the first one is showing up. Also I get 0's in column B if probably because they aren't all filled.

Comment: @Simon please see my edited answer. I actually used the same logic as **Harun24HR** so if you think my solution is working for you, you might give the credit to him. His solution is also working regardless if you have blank cell in Column B or W on your Sheet1.

Comment: I've worked out why I'm getting the 0's showing up. It's because `Column W` is a formula. I changed it just to a 0 instead of formula and the 0's in `sheet 2` went away. But I do need the formula in `Column W` as it's a counter of how many times `Column B` shows up in another sheet so is there a way to work around that?

Comment: I used both your formulas. The 0 shows up in `Sheet 2 Col B` for every "0" in `Col W` that is both the 0 resulting from the formula and without a value in in the matching row of `Col B`. I've tested it and it is a result of `Col W` having a formula and the formula returning a 0. I replaced some rows in `Col W` with just regular ol' 0 and the 0's in `Sheet 2 Col B` went away. You can try yourself where in your example you have a 0 next to blank, try making that 0 via a formula if you get same result as me.

Comment: Oh my god. It was all because of quote marks I used for Col W. In my IF statement I told it to put a "0" if it were true. I got rid of the "" and now no 0's show up in Sheet 2 -.-  Thanks man!

Comment: @Simon there are two exceptions that could cause your `Sheet 2 Col B` returns `0`: **1)** `Sheet 1 Col B` shows `0` while `Sheet 1 Col W` shows a `value>0`; **2)** both `Sheet 1 Col B` and `Sheet 1 Col W` are `blank`. My 3rd edit has eliminated the second exception. Let me know if you still come up 0 in `Sheet 2 Col B` and we may need to check if it was the first exception that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use `AGGREGATE()` formula to filter based on condition.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$5:$A$8,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$5:$A$8)-ROW($A$4))/($B$5:$B$8>0),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

[image]

Comment: What's the -ROW($A$4) and what do I set it to in mine? B4? `=IFERROR(INDEX('Sheet 1'!$B$5:$B$100,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW('Sheet 1'!$B$5:$B$100)-ROW('Sheet 1'!$B$4))/('Sheet 1'!$W$5:$W$100>0),ROW(1:1))),"")` is what I have. It works. Except for now I only have 2 things that have values >0. I paste this formula down the rows (Currently 5-20), row 5/6 show up good(as the 2 that have values >0, but row 7/8 have 0's in them then the rest are blank. Any particular reason they have 0's or how to get rid of them?

Comment: `ROW($A$4)` minus 4 from every row of `ROW($A$5:$A$8)`. So, it is becoming `1, 2, 3 .........` From this array we are getting row numbers for `Index($A$5:$A$8,....` function as index starts from 1 in excel. The formula output shouldn't come any 0. Is there any blank cell in `Column B` against `Column W` where `column W` has value greater than 0?

Comment: In `sheet 1` there can't be anything other than a 0 in `Column W` if there is nothing in `Column B`. I just tried it. Because `Column W` has formulas in it, it's got either a 0 or a number in it but `Column B` can be empty but there will still be a 0 in W if there is nothing in the matching row in B. Basically `W` is a counter of how many times the item in `B` shows up in another sheet. So the formulas in `W` cover the entire range, there may not be any values in it. Would it work adding in some sort of isblank check or something similar for column B to omit it if it is?